# Как изменить цвет галочки checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Так описан checkbox :

```
<input data-name="Subcategory 2" id="bapf_1_34" type="checkbox" value="34">
```

А вот ее стили:

```
    .bapf_sfilter.bapf_ckbox input[type=checkbox]{
background-color: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 5
px
;
    border-color: var(--primary);
}
```

Нужно изменить галочку на белый цвет, но уже окончательно запутался во всем.